# ¿Cómo crear box responsivo con bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, responsive

Tengo Tres Columnas dentro de un `div` con clase `.row` lo que quiero es que al reducir mi pantalla todo se me ajuste en una sola columna.

**Ejemplo**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Al reducir la pagina que se acomode de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien como se le pudiera dar `margin-bottom` para crear una separación vertical

Comment: Procura añadir algo de código para que sepámos qué has intentado o qué problemas estás teniendo. Al tratarse de librerías con diferentes versiones también es bueno que especifiques cuál es la que estás usando.

Comment: Recuerda agregar el código que tienes para que sea más fácil comprender lo que buscas y agregar información de los errores que tienes.

Comment: investiga sobre la propiedad de CSS "FLEX"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voy a suponer que estás usando la [última versión de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) a la fecha.

Lo primero que debes establecer en tu CSS es que tanto el `body` como el `html` tenga un alto que ocupe el 100% en la vista del dispositivo usando `height: 100%`, aunque lo más recomendable es usar la [unidad VH (viewport.)](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Lo siguiente simplemente es usar, tanto en el contenedor principal (`container`) como en sus filas (`row`), la [clase h-100](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent)  propia de Bootstrap 4, si usas la versión 3 únicamente añade esa clase dentro de tu CSS:

```
.h-100 {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Yo uso la clase [`container-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers) que ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla, algo así como usar la clase [`w-100`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row). Para añadir un `margin-bottom` a cada `div` puedes usar la clase [`mb-3`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width-multi-row) que en BS sería: `margin-bottom: 1rem !important`. Estos valores van desde mb-0 a mb-5

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.uno {
  background: #88BE6F;
}

.dos {
  background: #9389BE;
}

.tres {
  background: #FFF000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-3 uno"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-3 dos"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-3 tres"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Te invito a que leas y repases la [documentación oficial de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), su última versión es muy completa y robusta, aveces pecamos creando clases CSS propias que la librería ya trae de forma nativa.

Answer (score 0):

para ello tienes que usar las clases que tiene Bootstrap que son:

```
col-xs-
col-sm-
col-md-
col-lg-
```

cada una se ajusta dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla.
aquí puede encontrar la documentación https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

un ejemplo para ello seria asi:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="verde"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="morado"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
     <div class="amarillo"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

las columnas tienen que sumar un total de 12 así que si son 3 tienen que ir con con 4 cada una, pero cuando es versión mobile, se le coloca 12 para que se adapte a una sola columna.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: He establecido las columnas dentro de la clase `.row`, el problema es que al usar un dispositivo pequeño no se ajusta todo en una sola columna (height), solo se adaptan respecto al width.

Comment: seria que publicaras una parte del html para ver como lo estas haciendo

Comment: Algo como esto https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

Comment: Te recomiendo usar [UIKit Grid](https://getuikit.com/docs/grid) es mucho mas sencillo de utilizar incluso mas que bootstrap y trae una función que alinea perfectamente los elementos dependiendo del dispositivo. Además de que puedes añadirle una animación al scrollear [UIKit Scrollspy](https://getuikit.com/docs/scrollspy)

Comment: @FernyCortez buenos días. estos div se ajustan al width, si quieres que cuando se vean desde un celular su alto varíe tienes que crear un media query para el caso, esto lo puedes ver en el siguiente link -> [ACA](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/) en donde dice **Responsive breakpoints** tienes que crear uno para que en determinado with para un div tuyo el alto sea del tamaño que quieres